# How to create view in Snowflake based on a query that uses multiple roles and multiple databases?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have multiple Snowflake roles, each one gives me reading access to different data warehouses/databases. Also, I have one role that gives me write access to a Sandbox schema. Some of the latest projects I'm working on require manipulating and joining data across warehouses/databases. Selecting my role as ALL,  I have managed to query the data and view the final result in a Snowflake worksheet. However, when it comes to creating a view in the Sandbox schema, I get the following error:
"SQL compilation error: Cannot create permanent objects while using role ALL. Use TEMPORARY keyword to create a temporary object instead." Any idea how to workaround this error?

Answer (score 0):

This is an inherent limitation of the `ALL` role. You can get by (as the error instructs) by creating a table (first temporary, then permanent) instead of a view ([temporary views are not available](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-view.html)) if that's an option.

The use of `USE ROLE ALL;` shouldn't be pervasive in proper use of Snowflake, since it supports [hierarchal roles](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-configure.html#creating-a-role-hierarchy), with multiple privileges granted into a single assumed role.

Very limited object-mapped roles were necessary in other DBMS that lacked role hierarchies (or limited their levels). I recommend [revising your role creation and granting strategy](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-considerations.html#aligning-object-access-with-business-functions) to use Snowflake's access controls more effectively.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My query is an ETL that includes dynamic filters that needs to get updated quite often. If I create a table, would it be possible to refresh the contents periodically without the need to do so manually? My understanding Views can be updated automatically but tables can't.